# d3-attrTween with custom function.(What did I misunderstand about tween function?)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I have a question about attrTween (sometimes tween()).

I understood custom tween function as

after " attrTween('d' " argument,
I define the custom function.
So, I wrote the custom function as below.

```
        d3.selectAll('circle#circles1')
          .transition()
          .attrTween('d',function(){

            let interpolator=d3.interpolateArray(sdata.vader,sdata1.vader);
            return function(t){
                return d3.select(this).attr('cy',interpolator(t))
            }
          })
```

What I intended is

> For All the circles I drew,
>  makes a transition.
>  The transition
>   is attrTween.
>  The changes is based on data array tied into the
>   circles.
>  Original data array is sdata and the cy value in the
>   sdata is sdata.vader.
>  And the transition is heading toward
>   sdata1.and cy value for sdata1 is sdata1.vader.
>
> To access all the cy value for every single circle,
>  I used
>   d3.select(this).attr('cy')

However, no error message is shown but no animation was made either.

What did I misunderstand for the custom tween function?
Can anyone help me to fix this code?

Thank you inadvance.

Full code is in the following link.

https://codepen.io/jotnajoa/pen/WNQeEBE

Comment: Why are you using the `d` attribute? It makes little sense, only paths have the `d` attribute, not circles: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d. I suggest that, instead asking about your **attempted solution**, ask about your **real problem**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple problems in the example code, which is not minimal. Providing a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would really help solve the problems.

1. usage of HTML Id to multiple elements.

In HTML, and `id` attribute must be unique. Here, ids are assigned to groups of circles. A `class` attribute should be used for this purpose, not an `id`.

```
.attr('id','circles1')
```

should be:

```
.attr('class','circles1')
```

Accordingly, the `attrTween` should lookup the circles with class `circle1`, rather than the unique circle with id `#circle1`

```
d3.selectAll('circle#circles1')
```

should be

```
d3.selectAll('.circles1')
```

2. Id (or class) assigned in the wrong place.

The `circles1` class is assigned before the creation of the circle, hence the instructions applies to an empty selection. The class attribute should be set right after circles have been created.

```
.attr('id','circles1')
.enter()
  .append('circle')
```

should be

```
.enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('class','circles1')
```

3. Wrong attribute tweened

The attribute to transition is the circle's `cy` attribute, not a path's `d` attribute. Hence

```
.attrTween('d',function(){
```

should be

```
.attrTween('cy',function(){
```

4. Wrong data interpolated

`sdata.vader` and `sdata1.vader` do not exist, `sdata` and `sdata1` seem to be arrays of objects, which in turn do have a `vader` property.

You probably want `d.vader`, and the corresponding `.vader` in `sdata1`, which would be `sdata1[i].vader`, in case items are the same order in both arrays.

5. Interpolating original measures instead of coordinates.

`cy` is originally defined as:

```
height-yscale(d.vader)
```

In the interpolator function, the scale function should also be used.

The `attrTween` function calls becomes:

```
  .attrTween('cy',function(d, i){
    //console.log( i, height-yscale(d.vader), height-yscale(sdata1[i].vader))
    let interpolator=d3.interpolateArray(height-yscale(d.vader), height-yscale(sdata1[i].vader));

    return function(t) { return interpolator(t)}
  })
```

6. Using `attrTween` where not needed.

Simply transitioning the circles with `attr` is sufficient for this use case, there is no need to define an interpolator.

d3 will move the position of circles from the original position to the destination, interpolating implicitly.

```
d3.selectAll('.circles1')
  .transition()
  .duration(2000)
      .attr('cy',function(d, i){
      return height-yscale(sdata1[i].vader)
  })
```

I added a long duration for demo purpose, to make obvious that the circles move to the correct location. Once in their final position, they disappear, because they are under the pink circles.

P.S. Same set of corrections is applicable to `circles2` set whenever relevant.

Demo of the solution in the snippet below, as codepen does not allow to save modifications without creating an account.

```js
var svg;
var xscale;
var yscale;
var sdata;
var xAxis;
var yAxis;
var width=1500;
var height=500;
var margin=50;
var duration =250;
var vader ='vader'
var textblob='textblob'
var delay =5000;
var tbtrue=false;
var areas
var circles1,circles2;
var sdata1,sdata2

d3.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jotnajoa/Javascript/master/tweetdata.csv').then(function(data){
    svg=d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width',width).attr('height',height)

    var parser = d3.timeParse("%m/%d/%y")
    
    // data를 처리했고, date parser 하는 법 다시한번 명심하자.
    sdata = data;
    sdata.forEach(function(d){
        d.vader = +d.vader;
        d.textblob= + d.textblob;
        d.date=parser(d.date)
        
    })
   
   
    
   
    // scale을 정해야 함. 나중에 brushable한 범위로 고쳐야함. nice()안하면 정렬도안되고, 첫번째 엔트리 미싱이고
    // 난리도 아님.

    xscale=d3.scaleTime()
    .domain(d3.extent(sdata, function(d) {return d.date }))
    .range([0,width*9/10])
    .nice()

    

    yscale =d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain(d3.extent([-1,1]))
    .range([height*4/5,height*1/5])
    .nice()

    //yaxis는 필요 없을 것 같은데.

    //캔버스에 축을 그려야 함 단, translate해서 중간에 걸치게 해야함.

    svg.append('g').attr('class','xaxis')
       .call(d3.axisBottom(xscale))
       .attr('transform','translate('+margin+','+height*1/2+')')


    //sdata plotting
    
    var circles = svg.append('g').attr('class','circles')
    var area = svg.append('g').attr('class','pathline')
                   
    firststage();    
    //generator로 데이터를 하나씩 떨어뜨리도록 한다.
    function firststage(){
    function* vaderdropping(data){
        for( let i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            if( i%50==0) yield svg.node();

            let cx = margin+xscale(data[i].date)
            let cy = height-yscale(data[i].vader)

        circles.append('circle')
               .attr('cx',cx)
               .attr('cy',0)
               .transition()
               .duration(duration)
               .ease(d3.easeBounce)
               .attr('cy',cy)
               .attr('r',3)
               .style('fill','rgba(230, 99, 99, 0.528)')   
        }     
        yield svg.node()    

    }
    //generator 돌리는 부분
    
    let vadergen = vaderdropping(sdata);
    let result = vadergen.next()
    let interval = setInterval(function(){
        if(!result.done) {
          vadergen.next();
        }
        else {
         clearInterval(interval)
         
        }
     }, 100);
    setTimeout(secondstage,5000)
}
    

     function secondstage(){
     function* textblobdropping(data){
        for( let i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            if( i%50==0) yield svg.node();

            let cx = margin+xscale(data[i].date)
            let cy = height-yscale(data[i].textblob)

        circles.append('circle')
               .attr('cx',cx)
               .attr('cy',0)
               .transition()
               .duration(duration)
               .ease(d3.easeBounce)
               .attr('cy',cy)
               .attr('r',3)
               .style('fill','rgba(112, 99, 230, 0.528)')   
        }     
        yield svg.node()    

    }
    //generator 돌리는 부분
    
    let textblobgen = textblobdropping(sdata);
    let tresult = textblobgen.next()
    let tinterval = setInterval(function(){
        if(!tresult.done) {
          textblobgen.next();
        }
        else {
         clearInterval(tinterval)
        
        }
     }, 100);
     setTimeout(thirdstage,2500)
    }

    function thirdstage(){

        //진동을 만들기 위해서, 
        //베이다와 텍스트 블랍 값을 플립한거다 (제발 워크 아웃하길...)
        //그 다음 트윈으로 sdata 와 sdata1을 왔다갔다 하게하면 되지않을까?
             sdata1 = sdata.map(function(x){
                var y={};
                y['date']=x.date;
                y['vader']=x.textblob;
                y['textblob']=x.vader;
                return y});
             sdata2 = sdata.map(function(x){
                
                var y={};
                    y['date']=x.date;
                    y['vader']=0;
                    y['textblob']=0;
                    return y});
      
            d3.selectAll('circle').transition()
            .duration(3500)
            .style('fill','rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.228)')
            
            //areas는 일종의 함수다, 에리아에다가 데이터를 먹이면,
            //에리아를 그리는 역할을 하는것임.

            areas = d3.area()
            .x(function(d){return margin+xscale(d.date)})
            .y0(function(d){return height-yscale(d.vader)})
            .y1(function(d){return height-yscale(d.textblob)})
            .curve(d3.curveCardinal)

            //이렇게 하지말고, sdata2도 만들었으니까 2->1->0 반복하는
            // 무한반복 on('end','repeat') loop를 만들어보자.
            
            var uarea=area.append('path')
            setTimeout(repeat,500)
            
            function repeat(){
            uarea
            .style('fill','rgba(112, 99, 230, 0.4)')  
            .attr('d', areas(sdata))
            .transition()
            .duration(500)
            .attrTween('d',function(){
                var interpolator=d3.interpolateArray(sdata,sdata1);
                return function(t){
                    return areas(interpolator(t))
                }
            })
            .transition()
            .duration(500)
            .attrTween('d',function(){
                var interpolator=d3.interpolateArray(sdata1,sdata2);
                return function(t){
                    return areas(interpolator(t))
                }
            })
            .transition()
            .duration(500)
            .attrTween('d',function(){
                var interpolator=d3.interpolateArray(sdata2,sdata);
                return function(t){
                    return areas(interpolator(t))
                }
            })
            .on('end',repeat)
            }
            setTimeout(fourthstage,500)
        }

        function fourthstage(){
            // console.log(d3.selectAll('circle#circles1').node())

            circles1=svg.append('g').selectAll('circle').data(sdata)
                                   .enter().append('circle').attr('class','circles1')
                                   .attr('cx',function(d){return margin+xscale(d.date)})
                                   .attr('cy',function(d){return height-yscale(d.vader)})
                                   .style('fill','green')
                                   .attr('r',3)
            
            circles2=svg.append('g').selectAll('circle').data(sdata)
            .enter().append('circle').attr('class','circles2')
            .attr('cx',function(d){return margin+xscale(d.date)})
            .attr('cy',function(d){return height-yscale(d.textblob)})
            .style('fill','pink')
            .attr('r',3)

          d3.selectAll('.circles1')
            .transition()
            .duration(5000)
            .attr('cy',function(d, i){
            return height-yscale(sdata1[i].vader)
          })
            
            //   d3.selectAll('circle#circles2')
            //   .transition()
            //   .attr('cy',function(d){return 0})
            
            //tween 팩토리를 정의해야한다.
            //주의사항, 리턴을 갖는 함수여야한다는 것.
            
            //왜 꼭 return function(){}을 해야하나?
            /*
            function movey(d2){
                let y1 = this.attr('cy')
                let y2 = d2.vader
                let interpolate=d3.interpolate(y1,y2);
                interpolate;
            } 하면 안되나??
            */ 
            
                
            
        }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, for future I will try to debug more and leave the minimal things to be fixed. Really appreciate again!!